# Angular 6 - can't resolve all parameters for service on APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to load my settings on APP_INITIALIZER but compiler throws error of can't resolve all parameters for AppSettingService. Tried also to inject in the appSettingService constructor but still same error was thrown by the compiler.

**AppSettingService.service.ts**

```
import { AppSettings } from '../_models/appSettings';
import { BaseDataService } from '../base-data.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class AppSettingsService extends BaseDataService {


appSettings: AppSettings;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super();
    this.appSettings = null;
    this.setDebugSettings();
}

setDebugSettings() {

    this.appSettings = new AppSettings({
        baseApiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
    });
}

load(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
            .get('http://localhost:3000')
            .map((res: Response) =>  res.json())
            .toPromise()
            .then((data: any) => this.appSettings.baseApiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000')
            .catch( (err) => Promise.resolve());

  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
// factory method to get our config loaded at startup
export function configLoader(appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) {
  return () => appSettingsService.load();
 }
 providers: [
...,
AppSettingsService,
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: configLoader,
  deps: [AppSettingsService],
  multi: true
},
...
```

Comment: Can I please know the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the constructor of AppSettingsService

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => HttpClient)) private http: HttpClient)
```

Answer (score 0):

`AppSettingsService` has a dependency of `HttpClient`, so you should mark that as a dependency. Try:

```
AppSettingsService,
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: configLoader,
  deps: [AppSettingsService, HttpClient],
  multi: true
},
```

Also make sure that you have the `HttpClientModule` imported, like Suren pointed out.

Comment: after importing and providing httpclientModule the error still exist.

Answer (score 0):

@ANMOL,

Try this - it will make sure that the promise is resolved when it needs to and not at `toPromise()` - which happened to me and it wasn't obvious at first :

```
 load(): Promise<any> {                                    
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                                    
        this.http
            .get('http://localhost:3000')
            .map((res: Response) =>  res.json())
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.appSettings.baseApiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
                resolve();
                return data;
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject();
        })             
    });

    return promise;
}
```